# unknown fedora file system and partition settings

Tags: linux, partitioning, fedora

I've got a fedora system, who somebody has installed for me, and I don't precisely know what is:

- `lvm2pv`. I searched that LVM stands for "logical volume manager", but what is 2 and what is `pv` here?
- there are 2 partitions: `/boot` for boot partition - 100% clear, and `fedora` for the second partition. But what exactly is `fedora` - where is it on the hard drive? Is it something virtual?
- the space used by boot is ~25% (113MB/500MB). The space used by fedora is 465GB/465GB, no space left. And this is not true, since this is a brand clear OS with lots of space free (`files`, the fedora file manager, shows that 8GB is used and 454GB is free to be used).

Please answer/explain above questions. I'm using gparted to display the partition settings.

---

edit: below is the dump of `fdisk -l`:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 465.8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000971fc

Device    Boot     Start       End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *         2048   1026047    512000  83 Linux
/dev/sda2        1026048 976773119 487873536  8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-00: 3.9 GiB, 4198498304 bytes, 8200192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/fedora-01: 461.4 GiB, 495380856832 bytes, 967540736 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/sdb: 1.9 GiB, 2041577472 bytes, 3987456 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000c5505

Device    Boot Start       End  Blocks  Id System
/dev/sdb1 *     2048   3987455 1992704   b W95 FAT32


Disk /dev/mapper/luks-0feea8a9-42dc-42d9-bd7e-8b86c495e85b: 461.4 GiB, 495378759680 bytes, 967536640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-18332a23-b60e-4761-887c-233dd215ba85: 3.9 GiB, 4196401152 bytes, 8196096 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Comment: I doubt if "What the heck" expression is allowed in questions here. Anyways, can i request you to post a screen shot of the fdisk<space>-l (lowercase-L). This is help us understand the situation better.

Comment: @Prasanna you're right about my English. I've corrected the question and added `fdisk -l` result.

Comment: This looks like a LVM setup. See http://serverfault.com/a/28991/58408 and [edit] your post to include the output of running `lvscan` and `lvs`. My guess is that "lvm2pv" might be shorthand for "LVM to physical volume(s)"; "x2y" is a fairly common naming pattern for "x to y" translation.

Answer (score 0):

Meant as  clarification comment ---lacks rep tho:

lvm2 is  a reference to  version 2  or using metadata type 2  the default on MOST if not all linux distros these days

the pv  stands for Physical Volume

A quick primer  for you:

LVM uses a much more flexible  layout stucture to the older  "extended partition scheme of  MBR (old school) layouts.

Sample  LVM (mine actually --very ABNORMAL layout but should show the flexibility of  lvm and the seperate Volumes)

Showing the Volume Groups ( Can have Several Physical HDDs/SSDs as ONE from  the OS view)

http://paste.fedoraproject.org/210743/870714/

lines 2-3  of the above paste link show my  PVs (or physical volumes --in this case partitions)

lines 5-6  show the Volume Groups ( As server.linuxnet VG shows it has 12 sub volumes known as Logical Volumes)

lines 8-20 are my actual system --the Logical Volumes (also fedora --22 in my case)

what  you are seeing is a VG named fedora (presumably as fedora is installed --which is a flavor of linux)

The Volume group is in yours and my case taking the entire Drive the "Full Disk" is a slight misleading its stating the drive has no un allocated space not that all allocated space is used up...